# It is possible to create a login which doesn't need a password

Tags: mac, password, accounts

I was thinking that assigning passwords to OS X accounts is mandatory and you had to set the account to auto-login to avoid having to enter it every time. But can I also define a user account which doesn't need a password?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to set a password:

- Start with Create new user account in System preferences - Users & Groups
- Under drop down choose for example Standard Account
- Enter name and account but skip the password filed
- You will get a warning about not having password, click OK

Account is now created without password.

The Guest account (if enabled) also doesn't require a password.

Comment: Thank you, but you can connect via ssh only to admin account, and password is required in this case?

Comment: Actually you *can* set a blank password for an "Admin" account.

Comment: @TonyWilliams How can I do that. 1) When I try to create new account on Mavericks from "System Preferences" -> "Users & Groups" and I left blank password, I got "Name cannot be empty". 2) When I tried change later this password by terminal "sudo passwd ..." I also couldn't leave blank password.

Comment: I can only assume that you left the "Full Name" field empty. You have to fill in the "Full Name" and "Account name" fields but leave the passwords empty.